# Python command not found en Windows 10 con el substima de linux

Tags: python, ubuntu, bash, windows10

Bueno, resulta que tengo instalado Python en Windows 10 y recientemente instale el bash en ubuntu que esta disponible ahora en estas nuevas versiones, pero cuando realizo el típico python para correrlo este me da el mensaje de error al no encontrarlo.

¿Debería desinstalar el que ya tengo en Windows 10(incluso la variable de entorno) y volver a instalarlo desde el subsistema de linux o no creará conflicto alguno tener ambos instalados?

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con esto.

Gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Ambas instalaciones son completamente independiente: lo que tengas en Windows no afecta a lo que corras en Linux.

Answer (score 1):

En teoría **Python** ya está instalado en el subsistema **Bash de Ubuntu en Windows**, al menos [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) documento así lo especifica, creo que viene con la versión 2.7x y no encontré documentación para instalar alguna otra. Lo que seguramente te este faltando es el comando `pip` que puedes instalarlo con `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. con respecto a la versión "Windows" de Python, te comento que son entornos totalmente distintos, aislados e independientes.